# Metal equivalent to OpenGL mix

Tags: ios, swift, shader, metal

I'm trying to understand what is the equivalent of `mix` `OpenGL` function in metal. This is the `OpenGL` code I'm trying to convert:

```
float udRoundBox( vec2 p, vec2 b, float r )
{
    return length(max(abs(p)-b+r,0.0))-r;
}

void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    // setup
    float t = 0.2 + 0.2 * sin(mod(iTime, 2.0 * PI) - 0.5 * PI);
    float iRadius = min(iResolution.x, iResolution.y) * (0.05 + t);
    vec2 halfRes = 0.5 * iResolution.xy;

    // compute box
    float b = udRoundBox( fragCoord.xy - halfRes, halfRes, iRadius );

    // colorize (red / black )
    vec3 c = mix( vec3(1.0,0.0,0.0), vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0), smoothstep(0.0,1.0,b) );

    fragColor = vec4( c, 1.0 );
}
```

I was able to convert part of it so far:

```
float udRoundBox( float2 p, float2 b, float r )
{
    return length(max(abs(p)-b+r,0.0))-r;
}

float4 cornerRadius(sampler_h src) {

    float2 greenCoord = src.coord(); // this is alreay in relative coords; no need to devide by image size

    float t = 0.5;
    float iRadius = min(greenCoord.x, greenCoord.y) * (t);
    float2 halfRes = float2(greenCoord.x * 0.5, greenCoord.y * 0.5);

    float b = udRoundBox( float2(greenCoord.x - halfRes.x, greenCoord.y - halfRes.y), halfRes, iRadius );

    float3 c = mix(float3(1.0,0.0,0.0), float3(0.0,0.0,0.0), smoothstep(0.0,1.0,b) );

    return float4(c, 1.0);
}
```

But it's producing green screen. I'm trying to achieve corner radius on a video like so:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that `greenCoord` (which was only a good variable name for the other question you asked, by the way) is the relative coordinate of the *current pixel* and has nothing to do with the absolute input resolution.

If you want a replacement for your `iResolution`, use `src.size()` instead.

And it seems you need your input coordinates in absolute (pixel) units. You can achieve that by adding a `destination` parameter to the inputs of your kernel like so:

```
float4 cornerRadius(sampler src, destination dest) {
    const float2 destCoord = dest.coord(); // pixel position in the output buffer in absolute coordinates
    const float2 srcSize = src.size();

    const float t = 0.5;
    const float radius = min(srcSize.x, srcSize.y) * t;
    const float2 halfRes = 0.5 * srcSize;

    const float b = udRoundBox(destCoord - halfRes, halfRes, radius);

    const float3 c = mix(float3(1.0,0.0,0.0), float3(0.0,0.0,0.0), smoothstep(0.0,1.0,b) );

    return float4(c, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: Hey Frank! Thank you again. I figured it was a bad naming but I didn't risk it haha. Works! :) I'm starting to understand better what's going on, altho it took my half day today just to realize I need to initialize the `CIContext` with Metal and not with `EAGL context` just to make it render

Comment: Hey Frank, just encountered new issues regards memory consumption on our previously made VHS filter. Seems like when we are using 4K videos - it's super hard for the device, and it's crashing. The thing is that the final output our app produce is not more than 1080p than we are doing extra work for nothing. If you have a spare min, I'd love if you could take a look and guide me in the right direction (as always ). Here's a link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57153640/metal-resize-video-buffer-before-passing-to-custom-kernel-filter . Thank you so much, no words!

Answer (score 5):

The mix function is an implementation of linear interpolation, more frequently referred to as a Lerp function.

You can use linear interpolation where you have a value, let's say t and you want to know how that value maps within a certain range.

For example if I have three values:

a = 0
b = 1 
and
t = 0.5

I could call mix(a,b,t) and my result would be 0.5. That is because the mix function expects a start range value, an end range value and a factor by which to interpolate, so I get 0.5 which is halfway between 0 and 1.

Looking at the documentation Metal has an implementation of mix that does a linear interpolation.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for explaining the fundamentals for me, it's a long road till I'll catch all the basic operation within Metal/OpenGL!