# Standard Swift function implementing mix/lerp for linear interpolation?

Tags: swift

I'm curious is there a function implementing [Linear Interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) of two values in stock Apple Swift Packages?

I see that [Metal has a mix function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57140391/14840926) that should do what I need, but I haven't found any sample code that I can pop into a swift file, nor do I see any sign of `mix` in current Xcode docs. I have no experience with Metal, so I'm unsure where to start, beyond `import Metal`.

Could someone point out how to use that `mix` function, or alternatively, point to an alternate implementation, so long as it doesn't involve downloading 3rd party packages?

Of course, I know how to implement such a simple function for my particular situation, but I'd rather not re-implement the wheel, and I imagine Apple could have a more elegant Generics-based solution than I could make.

Answer (score 0):

The Accelerate framework has a few implementations of Lerp that you can use, you can see the full list on [this site](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vdsp/linear_interpolation_functions).

The Accelerate framework is designed for fast processing of large amounts of values, so it may be overkill to use it with a single value, and not the most ergonomic function to call, but you could wrap it into a simpler function call.

Using it would look like this

```
import Accelerate

let start: Double = 5
let end: Double = 10
let progress: Double = 0.5

let value = vDSP.linearInterpolate([start], [end], using: progress)[0]
```